# get apache total cpu usage in (linux)

Tags: linux, apache, cpu

I want to write a script (in bash or Perl on linux) which monitors the Apache and restarts the Apache in case it exceeds X% CPU.
I understand that I need to get the total CPU usage of Apache since it opens child process.

How can I get the total CPU usage of Apache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following, but make sure to update the Apache-process name with your actual one (mine is `httpd`):

```
ps u -C httpd | awk '{sum += $3} END {print sum}'
```

This will get a list of all apache processes running and sum the `%CPU` column of `ps`'s output using `awk`.

Comment: ps u -C apache returns an empty result

Comment: @Shay is `apache` the name of your apache process? I've seen `httpd` and `apache2`, but never just `apache`?

Comment: The name is apache2 but with apache2 the command also returns empty

Comment: @Shay You can try `ps u -U apache`, in this case, `apache` is the user-account running Apache. If this doesn't work, can you verify that Apache is running and, if so, run `ps aux` and display the output so that we can see the process list to get the process or user name?

Comment: Is it correct to sum the cpu percent of all apache child process? Each process can run on a different cpu, no?

Comment: @Shay Are you saying that you want the total CPU Percentage for Apache - per CPU? My method above will give you the **total** CPU utilization for Apache (including the child processes); I may be mistaken, but I don't think that there is a way to determine a per-CPU percentage.

Comment: If one single apache process eats up 100% CPU (that is, one core) over a longer period there must be something wrong, no need to sum up the CPU usage of multiple processes.

Comment: @scai The OP's question asks for the total, or did I misread?

Comment: @newfurniturey yes and your answer is basically correct. Yet it doesn't help much to geht the total CPU usage of all processes in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

this will return sum load of parent apache process and all child processes, in percents, without any additional info, so that you can easily use this script in any way:

```
ps --no-heading -o pcpu -C httpd | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This will list you the total CPU usage of each apache2 process:

```
ps u -C apache2 | awk '{print $3}' | grep -v "%CPU"
```

Note, however, that the total (=average) CPU usage might be rather low even if the current CPU usage is high, especially for long running processes.